# can not access element in directive template template

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to access DOM object of template from link function  in a directive but I can't. I want to access this canvas object to change it after some file upload

```
MakeApp
        .directive('fileUploaderDir', function ($location) {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                scope: {
                },
                template: function (elem , attr) {
                    if(attr.maxNumberFile<=1){
                        return'<tbody ng-init="changeCanvas">' +
                        '<tr ng-repeat="item in uploader.queue">' +
                        '<td  ><strong>{{ item.file.name }}</strong>' +
                '<canvas id="canvasImgUpload"/>' +
                '</td>' +
                        '<td ng-show="uploader.isHTML5" nowrap>{{ item.file.size/1024/1024|number:2 }} MB</td>' +
                        '<td ng-show="uploader.isHTML5">' +
                        '<div class="progress" style="margin-bottom: 0;">' +
                        '<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" ng-style="{ \'width\': item.progress + \'%\' }"></div>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '</td>' +
                        '<td class="text-center">' +
                        '<span ng-show="item.isSuccess"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>' +
                        '<span ng-show="item.isCancel"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i></span>' +
                        '<span ng-show="item.isError"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></span>' +
                        '</td>' +
                        '<td nowrap>' +
                        '<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" ng-click="item.upload()" ng-disabled="item.isReady || item.isUploading || item.isSuccess">' +
                        '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> Upload' +
                        '</button>' +
                        '<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" ng-click="item.cancel()" ng-disabled="!item.isUploading">' +
                        '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></span> Cancel' +
                        '</button>' +
                        '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" ng-click="item.remove()">' +
                        '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Remove' +
                        '</button>' +
                        '</td>' +
                        '</tr>' +
                        '</tbody>' 

                    }
                    else {
                        return '<div class="modal-container" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-h">'
                    }
                },

                      link : function($scope, element, attrs) {
           // $scope.canvasImgUpload = element.getElementById('canvasImgUpload');
           // $scope.canvasImgUpload =  element.find('canvas')[0];
         // $scope.contextImgUpload =  $scope.canvasImgUpload.getContext('2d');

           $scope.changeCanvas=function(){
               $scope.canvasImgUpload    = angular.element(document.querySelector('#canvasImgUpload'));
               console.log("canvass" , $scope.canvasImgUpload);
           }
           $scope.$watch('uploader.queue' , function () {
               alert('queue changeeee');

           })



       }
```

I want to access canvas in the template but it return empty object! Can anyone tell me why ?

Comment: Can you show how your directive is applied in html?

Comment: @BartekFryzowicz  <div class="col-sm-5" file-uploader-dir java-ctrl-url="fileUpload" type="image" max-number-file="1"></div>
                                </div> 
I have more parameters in scope but i removed them from code above to more clarity

Comment: @faraa. Be clear on your requirement. If you want to access the `template` before adding to the browser you can do so in `compile` function. `element` in `link` function represent the host element that invokes the directive

Comment: @GangadharJannu I want to access canvas dynamically..I have a table and inside that I have some rows...This rows adds to table as user uploads a file(si for eac row I have a canvas)...I edited my code to show template more complete...Can you tell me my mistake ?

Comment: @faraa I'm sure you are still unclear about what to do. Explain what you want to do in a action sequence so that we will help you in solving the issue

Comment: @GangadharJannu I think my problem is that I get canvas before loading model . But I should get canvas for each row when table changes and row added...Can you explain me How can I do it?\

Answer (score 0):

The reason probably is that you trying to access a DOM element before it is inserted.

Solution could be to use **ng-init** in the template.
For example:

HTML template:

```
<div class="modal-container" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-h" 
ng-init='changeCanvas()'>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Directive Link Script:

```
link : function($scope, element, attrs) {    
       $scope.changeCanvas=function(){
       $('#canvas').doSomething();
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply...I edited my code to show template more completely...I added this function in above code too..But it does not work yet! Now this function doesn't call at all!

Comment: use the brackets to call the function. like:
ng-init='changeCanvas()'

Comment: Thanks...Now it is called. But its empty yet!

Comment: what is uploader in the above html. Its not very clear what is being uploaded and how?

Still a couple of things you can note are:
1. Write a template in an html file and use its url to link it to directive. your code will be more understandable and easier for you to write.
2. if you are using <input type='file'> remember that angular doesn't provide you the feature to attach it to a model. you need to create a custom directive for that.

Comment: I am using angular-file-upload plugin. I extended it in a new directive...now I want to add Icon for each row in directive